# How to retrieve data of Cross object using SOQL query?

Tags: soql, cross-object

I have 3 Objects i.e Object A ,Object B,Object C

1)Object A is the Master object of Object B and Object C
(Object A --> Object B) , (Object A --> Object C)

2)There is no relation between Object B and Object C

Now the question is ,how would I retrieve the Object C fields using Object B ?

I would retrieve the result but I don't want in Json format as result , I want to export and see the Object C values in individual column

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "semi-join" (a subquery in the WHERE clause) to perform a query on your parent object A.

From there, you can perform a parent-child subquery (a subquery in the SELECT clause) to get at records of object C.

It'll look something like this

```
[SELECT
    Id,
    (SELECT Id, <other fields> FROM ObjectC_Child_Relationship_Name)
 FROM ObjectA__c
 WHERE Id IN (SELECT ObjA_lookup__c FROM ObjectB__c WHERE Id IN :listOfObjBIds)
]
```

Things to take note of:

- The parent-child subquery requires the *child relationship name*, which is not the same as the api name of the child object.It's usually the plural (+ __r if it's a custom relationship field)
- Relationships in Salesforce are one-to-many, so your ObjectB record is almost certainly going to have more than one ObjectC step-siblings

For a practical example, let's try to get the `Contact` records related to the `Account` that a given `Opportunity` is related to.

```
[SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Contacts)
 FROM Account
 WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIdsList)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working now after writing the below inner query 
select Id,Name ,(select Id from ObjectB__r),(select Id from ObjectC__r) from ObjectA

And also able to access the inner query fields using the for loop

for(ObjectA__c objA : query){
  for(ObjectB__c objB : objA.ObjectB__r){
  }
  for(ObjectC__c objc : objA.ObjectC__r){
  }
}